# Api auth security with laravel 4, ios and Api Keys

Tags: api, security, rest, laravel, oauth

After look`in for it around the day cant seem to find the right answer to my problem.

Situation:
Starting on L4 and planned to make an medium-large application, the framework consists an iOs app (later on there will be an android, maybe an windows) that interacts with an REST API (build in L4) and an web application also in l4.

The (iOs/android) app will be able to have login functionality and can change certain stuff in the database via the API. The web application can be logged into and can also change stuff in the database.

now my question:
the communication between the api and (iOs/Android) app has to be secure because of the sending of personal information like password, username, email-adress, names etc... How can i secure this? I heard about Oauth1.0a and 2.0 but since im not an extremely large project it seems to be an overkill, a lot of work and unnecessary.  I also heard about apikeys(random key can be based on ex. pasword or username) and send them over SSL, it seems to me an fair idea but i do not understand it 100%.

Questions about apikeys:

1. As in tutorials ive seen you make an random key in the api on registration. How will the app know what my apikey is? For instance do i have to send it over?
2. Should the apikey be random? Or does i have to have information inside it? like an username encrypt en decrypt.

I also would refer to this Laracast that explains the authentication on api's

http://youtu.be/xa-FRWDxJrI?t=24m59s

Thanks in advance an i'd really like to see your idea's about this topic!

Comment: Found that with ssl im ready and save enough beside this you could allways do some tricks like private public keys in combination width an unique encryption you should be fine.